# Cannot find macro `vec` in this scope when using pallet-staking

Tags: pallet, staking, compilation

I am trying to implement the prebuilt `pallet-staking` using `4.0.0-dev` and tag `devhub/latest`. I am getting a compilation error on `npos-elections`. Should I be able to add the staking pallet into the runtime and it would use the correct dependency?  Any recommendation?

```
error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/max/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/npos-elections/src/lib.rs:367:45
    |
367 |         Self { total: Default::default(), voters: vec![] }
    |                                                   ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            crate::sp_std::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec
```

Here is the implementation of the pallet in the runtime:

```
impl pallet_staking::Config for Runtime {
  type MaxNominations = ConstU32<16>;
  type Currency = Balances;
  type UnixTime = pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Self>;
  type CurrencyToVote = frame_support::traits::SaturatingCurrencyToVote;
  type RewardRemainder = ();
  type Event = Event;
  type Slash = ();
  type Reward = ();
  type SessionsPerEra = ();
  type SlashDeferDuration = ();
  type SlashCancelOrigin = frame_system::EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
  type BondingDuration = ();
  type SessionInterface = Self;
  type EraPayout = pallet_staking::ConvertCurve<RewardCurve>;
  type NextNewSession = Session;
  type MaxNominatorRewardedPerValidator = ConstU32<64>;
  type OffendingValidatorsThreshold = ();
  type ElectionProvider = onchain::OnChainSequentialPhragmen<Self>;
  type GenesisElectionProvider = Self::ElectionProvider;
  type MaxUnlockingChunks = ConstU32<32>;
  type SortedListProvider = pallet_staking::UseNominatorsMap<Self>;
  type BenchmarkingConfig = pallet_staking::TestBenchmarkingConfig;
  type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

And here is my dependency in `runtime/Cargo.toml`

```
pallet-staking = {version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", tag = "devhub/latest"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you didn't put `pallet-staking/std` into the list of enabled features of `std` of your runtime.

Comment: Doh! That's it, ty